# Qt signals and slots. Slider and progress bar

Tags: c++, qt

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), 
        ui->progressBar, SLOT(setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->value()-100)));
```

I tried to connect signals and slots when the value of slider for example is 30, the value of the progress bar should be 70 but nothing is changed, I can't find mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome aboard.

I am surprised that you want to do a calculation inside the connect. This is not how it works.
Please add a slot (method) like

```
void slotSetValue(int input)
{
  ui-progressBar->setValue(100 - input);
}
```

and connect like
`connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this,slotSetValue(int)));`

Fine-tuning for your code may be needed.

ps. I recommend to use the Qt5-connects, which are compile-time-checked.

Answer (score 1):

You normally do :

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, 
ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::setValue);
```

but your logic is not correct because you are connecting a **valueChanged** with a **setValue** , that will crash your app since an overflow will happen...

on the other hand, connect used to only pipe signals and slots, you can not do math in the signals/functions involved in that, at least not like that... you will need a lambda or something similiar in the  middle